# Why does my Antlr give error: rule prog contains a closure with at least one alternative that can match an empty string to my grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am using Antlr4 4.12 version for parser generator on Intellij IDE
**My grammar :**

```
grammar new_g;

prog: (statements)+ | EOF ;

statements: simplestatement | compoundstatement ;

simplestatement:
  DOC paramlist  ;

compoundstatement:
  TABLE paramlist tabledata TABLE |
  QUIZ paramlist .*? QUIZ |
  QUESTION paramlist .*? QUESTION |
  ;

paramlist: '(' param (',' param)* ')' ;

param: VAR '=' STR ;

tabledata: tablerow(':'tablerow )*;

tablerow: (INT|FLOAT|VAR|STR)(',' (INT|FLOAT|VAR|STR))* ;
// tokens
DOC: '%doc';
TABLE: '%table';
//COMMENT:'%c' ;
//GRAPH: '%graph';
QUIZ: '%quiz';
QUESTION: '%question';
INT: [0-9]+ ;
FLOAT: [+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+ ;
//GVAR:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ; 
VAR:  [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ; // abc123 a_123_xyZ
STR: '"'[a-zA-Z0-9., ]*'"';
//COMMENT_STR: '% ' .* ; 
WS: [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
//COMMENT_STR: '%c' ([\n] {skip();})? [a-zA-Z0-9., ]* '%c';
```

How can I make sure that no subrule for `prog rule matches any empty string

Comment: Have you intended to add the `|` after `QUESTION` or is it just a typo  ?

Comment: The problem happens when you are trying to use the `+`-, `*`-, or `*`-operators on a block (typically just a parser rule name) that derives the empty string. Here, `compoundstatement` can derive the empty string, That means `statements` can derive the empty string.  In the `prog` rule, you are taking the `+`-closure: `(statements)+`. BTW, the parentheses are useless around `statements`. Remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` operator in an ANTLR grammar can be read as an `OR`.

Your `compoundstatement` is formatted so that it reads more as an "alternative terminator"

```
compoundstatement:
  TABLE paramlist tabledata TABLE |
  QUIZ paramlist .*? QUIZ |
  QUESTION paramlist .*? QUESTION |
  ;
```

If you use the ANTLR plugin for VSCode, it will reformat it as:

```
compoundstatement
    : TABLE paramlist tabledata TABLE
    | QUIZ paramlist .*? QUIZ
    | QUESTION paramlist .*? QUESTION
    |
    ;
```

This makes it pretty easy to see that the rule has a final alternative that matches "nothing" (a.k.a an "empty string").

This is the source of your error:

This corrects the warning:

```
compoundstatement
    : TABLE paramlist tabledata TABLE
    | QUIZ paramlist .*? QUIZ
    | QUESTION paramlist .*? QUESTION
    ;
```

NOTE: reading `|` as `OR` also makes it clear that the `prog` rule itself:

```
prog: (statements)+ | EOF;
```

is probably not what you intend.  It says that is matches one of more `statements` **OR** EOF.

It's a good practice to have any start rules consume all input through the OEF, so you probably want:

```
prog: statements+ EOF;
```

(Maybe also consider renaming `statements` to `statement` as the rule only matches a single statement.)